# memory issues with big numpy/scipy arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management, numpy, scipy

I've the below code snippet:

`data`/`imat` are data matrices of `100000 x 500`, while the matrix `S` which I'm constructing is of the order `50000 x 100000`. But the matrix `S` is super sparse with only one entry in each column

```
def getSparseCovErr(imat, sketch):
   ATA = np.dot(imat.transpose(), imat)
   BTB = sketch.transpose().dot(sketch)
   fn = np.linalg.norm(imat, 'fro') ** 2
   val = np.linalg.norm(ATA - BTB , 2)/fn
   del ATA
   del BTB
   return val

nrows, ncols = data.shape
samples = noOfSamples(ncols, eps, delta)

cols = np.arange(nrows)
rows = np.random.random_integers(samples - 1, size = nrows)
diag = []
for i in range(len(cols)):
    if np.random.random() < 0.5:
        diag.append(1)
    else:
        diag.append(-1)
S = sparse.csc_matrix((diag, (rows, cols)), shape = (samples, nrows))/np.sqrt(samples)
Q = S.dot(data)

Q = sparse.bsr_matrix(Q)

print getSparseCovErr(data, Q)
```

When I run the above code for the first time it gives me the print statement output. After that, if I do another run I get the below error:

```
python: malloc.c:2369: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

Then if I run once again, I get something like:

```
    Q = sparse.bsr_matrix(Q)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/bsr.py", line 170, in __init__
    arg1 = coo_matrix(arg1, dtype=dtype).tobsr(blocksize=blocksize)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 186, in __init__
    self.data  = M[self.row, self.col]
IndexError: index -1517041769959067988 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 178133
None
```

It seems to me like the first run I do is creating memory issues. How can I debug this and what are the possible problems and solutions?

Comment: This is really hard to answer since the code is only runnable by you. But could you clarify which part you re-run and which, if any variables you need after the print statement

Comment: @deinonychusaur I run the code that I have posted here the way it is.

Comment: @deinonychusaur  The variable Q can be eliminated but then I would need to do the operation S.dot(A) inside every error function and this also gives the same errors. When I first run the code as it is, the print statement gives an output, after that if I run again it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
def getSparseCovErr(imat, sketch):
   return np.linalg.norm(np.dot(imat.transpose(), imat) - sketch.transpose().dot(sketch)) / (np.linalg.norm(imat, 'fro') ** 2)

def getQ(data, rows, cols, diag, samples, nrows):
    return sparse.bsr_matrix((sparse.csc_matrix((diag, (rows, cols)), shape = (samples, nrows))/np.sqrt(samples)).dot(data))

print getSparseCovErr(data, getQ(data, rows, cols, diag, samples, nrows))
```

That is, trying to get things out of scope as soon as possible. Might be some parenthesis wrong since it's hard to test without the functions.

If not, I would assume one of your functions you are storing is actually changing the state / storing data.

Using your original code and given that you use ipython you can do the following:

```
In [5]: %%bash
ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n | pr -TW$COLUMNS | tail -n 10
```

To monitor the allocation of memory for each step of your code to nail down the problem.

Comment: I actually have the code in seperate functions itself. I'm not using ipython, but I possibly should now. I'm suspecting that this might due to number of non zero entries the sparse matrix * dense data matrix multiplication produces.

Comment: But if no information stays in state, it should be no problem repeating the execution. Anyhow checking when memory allocation happens is probably a good start.